# Intel HD graphics + dedicated PhysX card

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, physx

I have an Intel HD 530 and a NVidia 9800GTX+.

The Intel chip is more powerful at graphics but the NVidia card will be better in physics tasks.

I could only find setups with two NVidia cards.

Also the NVidia control panel closes or doesn't open if no screen is connected.

1. *How can I dedicate the NVidia card to PhysX without video output?*
2. *Can I make the card only run when it is needed?*